# How to continuously show command output in bash?

Tags: bash, output

I have a code in my bash script

`OUTPUT=""yum update`

`echo $OUTPUT`

`echo $OUTPUT >> mylogfile`

`yum update`is a very long command and without my script it always output something to console, but in my script it starts, for the long time nothing outputs and after a while outputs a lof of data.
Is any way in my script to output data as soon as it is available, but not all data in the same time after long waiting?

Comment: You are "suffering from buffering".  I can't test this, but try redirecting stdout to stderr, which should be unbuffered.  `yum update >&2`

Answer (score 3):

Try using [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29):

```
$ yum update | tee mylogfile
```

will send standard output from yum to *both* the standard output of shell (your screen) and `mylogfile`. Add redirections for standard error as needed.